# casting unsigned char * buffer to a callable void pointer that can take an argument

Tags: c++, c

The problem i have is that i don't know how to do the casting properly, my objective is to call the method that will be placed in the buf.

This is my compiler error.

> error: ‘buf’ cannot be used as a function

This is my current code

```
...

unsigned char *getFileBuffer(const char filename[], long &fileSize)
{
    ...
}

void (*ptrox)(int &) = NULL;

int main()
{
    long filesize = -1;
    int x = 3;

    //buf will consist of a operation, that takes an referenced int as an argument.
    unsigned char *buf = getFileBuffer("foo", filesize);

    //This is obviously not correct and does not match the description.
    ptrox = (void *)&buf(int &);

    ptrox(x);

    cout << x;
}
```

And this is the actual method / buffer.

```
void i(int &x)
{
    x += 2;
}

__Z1iRi:
0000000100000cbb    55                  pushq   %rbp
0000000100000cbc    4889e5              movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000cbf    48897df8            movq    %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000cc3    488b45f8            movq    -0x8(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000cc7    8b00                movl    (%rax), %eax
0000000100000cc9    8d5002              leal    0x2(%rax), %edx
0000000100000ccc    488b45f8            movq    -0x8(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000cd0    8910                movl    %edx, (%rax)
0000000100000cd2    5d                  popq    %rbp
0000000100000cd3    c3                  ret
```

Comment: Do you need the answer for C or C++ because it will be different.

Comment: C++ please, but if you can provide an explanation in what differ between them that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct typecast would look like this:

```
ptrox = (void (*)(int &))buf;
```

Why don't you use `dlopen`/`dlsym` for loading functions? Will be less error prone. Also by default your memory into which you load your function will **not** be executable, so if you try to run `ptrox` it will get a `SIGSEGV`.

In order to use `libdl` you would need to compile your function `foo` for example in a shared library and load it like this:

```
void * libhandle = dlopen("foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (!libhandle) {
    perror("dlopen");
    abort();
}
ptrox = (void (*)(int &))dlsym(libhandle,
    "foo" // C function name (use extern "C" where appropriate)
    );
if (!ptrox) {
    perror("dlsym");
    abort();
}
```

If you require to load a C++ function pointer to be loaded then you will need to use it's mangled function name. Consult `nm foo.so` for it.

How to `mmap` executable memory:

```
void * getFileBuffer(const char filename[], long fileSize) {
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        abort();
    }
    void * buf = mmap(
          NULL
        , fileSize
        , PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC
        , MAP_PRIVATE
        , fd
        , 0
    );
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("map");
        abort();
    }

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: The file 'foo' only consists of the binary instructions, my plan here is to try to inject a method into my program that runs and modifies the x.

Comment: Except that this cast is illegal, at least in pre-C++11 (and only conditionally supported in C++11).  The correct way of doing the assignment is `*(void**)(&ptrox) = dlsym( libhandle, "foo" );`.  The same technique can be used for the originally requested cast, but in that case, be aware that it may not work correctly on all platforms (function pointers and data pointers may have different sizes).  (Posix requires it to work.)

Comment: @Ogelami In that case make sure that the memory that contains your loaded binary instructions is executable. Beware that on most modern systems memory can not be writeable and executable at the same time. I would still recommend to use the dynamic loader for more portability.

Comment: Oh, i really had no idea that it couldn't be writeable/executable at the same time.

Comment: @Ogelami It can be readable and executable, but generally OSes will refuse to make memory writeable and executable simultaneously in order to avoid certain types of attacks.

Comment: So, how will i write this into a non-writable section of the memory? :)

Comment: @Ogelami You have two options: 1. `mmap` your file straight away with `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC` Or 2. create anonymous memory (also with `mmap`), read your file into it and then `mprotect` it to `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`.

Comment: So this is the reason why i get "Bus error: 10" when i run the function because that region of the memory don't have the PROT_EXEC flag?
and how about mprotect(buf, filesize, PROT_EXEC); ?

Comment: @Ogelami It could have any number of reasons, but this is the most likely one. Your memory needs to be read/exec, not just exec. Also I would not modify protection flags for heap pages. Allocate special pages for this. By the way `mprotect` only works on page-aligned addresses and works in chunks of pages.

Comment: @Ogelami I have added sample code of how to load your file into executable memory.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following construct works:
`ptrox = (void (*)(int &))buf;` but don't know why the paranthesis around * is needed.

how i usually handle this:

```
typedef void *pfunc(int &);
```

then i can use

```
ptrox = (pfunc)buf;
```

Comment: Parenthesis are used, so that `*` is not misinterpreted as a part of return type (`void *`). In fact, you should probably use them with `typedef` too.

Comment: This conversion is conditionally supported (C++11), or illegal (earlier versions of C++).  In practice, it was often (illegally) allowed, but there is generally no guarantee that pointers to functions have the same size as pointers to data.

Comment: damn, forgot them on the typedef, but for me it makes more sense on the typedef, it says that pfunc is a pointer to a function, (encloses the identifier and the *).